# Not able to load images from static folder in django

Tags: django, django-settings

Not able to load image from static dir in Django. Below is the picture of my file structure. [image]

In `settings.py` S

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

When I try to load the image file from `STATIC_URL`, it is producing this error:
[image]

it is just not loading images but the text from my `home-view.html` is loading file thus django is not able to locate the image files. Could you please advise why are images not loading?

home-view.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        {{time}} 
        
        <img src="{% static 'myproject/images/test.png' %}" alt="My image">
        
    </head>
</html>
```

---

My complete `settings.py` file :

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os 
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

print("Path is : ",  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/template'))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-(ep(j)h+$(zro2!9r3bm0fj^!84-1c9d+)$be4hgrq4_#6d^r-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myproject'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
print("static path" , STATICFILES_DIR)
print(STATIC_URL)
# print("static file : ", (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')), )
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
```

Do this and try:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'appname/static'),]
```

and also add this:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'appname', 'templates')

{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        {{time}} 
        
        <img src="{% static '/myproject/images/test.png' %}" alt="My image">
        
    </head>
</html>
```

and make sure you create folder called templates instead of template

I hope this may be help you